# How to get Screw Default Buttons plugin working with dynamically added checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a cool plugin that let's one easily change the appereance of a radio/checkbox:

http://www.screwdefaultbuttons.com/

My problem is, that it doesnt work on checkboxes that are dynamically added.

Here is my code:

```
function createCheckBoxes() {
    $('input:checkbox').screwDefaultButtons({
        image: "url(/content/img/checkbox_png.png)",
        width: 19,
        height: 19
    });
}
```

Is it possible to make it work with dynamically added checkboxes aswell ?

There checkboxes are dynamically added when using paging in a GridView (ASP.NET) so i can't just call the function again

Comment: Is your gridview in update panel?

Comment: Yes the GridView is in an UpdatePanel

Comment: try to call createCheckBoxes() after you dynamically add new checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i think it might resolve your issue.

You might use this script. when ever update panel updates i mean ajax request is done you have to add `add_endRequest()` event handler in javascript.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(createCheckBoxes);

function createCheckBoxes() {
        $('input:checkbox').screwDefaultButtons({
            image: "url(/content/img/checkbox_png.png)",
            width: 19,
            height: 19
        });
    }
```

The above code will be executed whenever you do paging, or any ajax request is done.

First try putting alert in the function while clicking any page number in grid

Comment: No no, you have to add this above your javascript `createCheckBoxes()` As i have clearly mentioned in my answer.